# AngularJS function not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

There are no errors or warnings. This function doesn't display the result, instead it shows as:

`{{student.fullName}}`

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Sample</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div ng-app = "mainApp" ng-controller="studentController">
    Enter first name: <input type = "text" ng-model = "student.firstName"><br><br>
    Enter last name: <input type = "text" ng-model = "student.lastName"><br>
    <br>

    your full name is: {{student.fullName()}}
 </div>

 <script>
    var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []);

    mainApp.controller('studentController', function($scope) {
       $scope.student = {
          firstName: "Narasimha",
          lastName: "Rao",

          fullName: function() {
             var studentObject;
             studentObject = $scope.student;
             return studentObject.firstName + " " + studentObject.lastName;
          }
       };
    });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**output:**

[image]

Comment: I put your code in a CodePen and it worked correctly.

Comment: I just copied your code in a textfile saved it as .html and it works without problems. Do you have any other scripts or errors in dev tools

Answer (score 0):

Works like a charm

```js
var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []);

    mainApp.controller('studentController', function($scope) {
       $scope.student = {
          firstName: "Narasimha",
          lastName: "Rao",

          fullName: function() {
             var studentObject;
             studentObject = $scope.student;
             return studentObject.firstName + " " + studentObject.lastName;
          }
       };
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app = "mainApp" ng-controller="studentController">
    Enter first name: <input type = "text" ng-model = "student.firstName"><br><br>
    Enter last name: <input type = "text" ng-model = "student.lastName"><br>
    <br>

    your full name is: {{student.fullName()}}
 </div>
```

Comment: thank you for letting me know that i have just tried it and it works fine. i don't know why it is not working in eclipse. i also used other editors like vscode and sublime text all gave me the same results.

Comment: @NarsimRao what do you mean by editor? what happens when you open it in a Browser like Chrome or Firefox?

Comment: i have attached the image of the output. i get this output browser like chrome, firefox even used plunker but i can't get the output correctly except in code pen don't know why in codepen it executes perfectly.

Comment: @NarsimRao check if you have permission to reach https://ajax.googleapis.com, check the console log in the develepor tool in chrome (F12) and look for errors

Answer (score 0):

The code is working properly. What are you using to run your file?

Comment: using eclipse oxygen and running it on chrome and yes the code is working in codepen.

Comment: Ya. So the code is right. There might be some other reason which you will have to figure out. `Tip: Sometimes making the whole function again, works.`